# How to change the tempateurl on button clcik

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to change the tempateUrl from home.html to customer.html on button click.

```
first2.directive('mycustomer', function() 
{
    return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: 'true',
            template: 'home.html',//want to change this customer.html on button click
          }
});
```

Is this possible

Comment: is it possible to use two module in single page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have two templates called aaa.html and bbb.html.
If you want your choose dynamically between them in your directive you could write

```
app.directive('mycustomer', function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: function(el, attr) {
      return attr.template + '.html';
    }
  }
});
```

and then called them like this

```
<div mycustomer template="aaa"></div>
<div mycustomer template="bbb"></div>
```

Comment: is it possible to use two module in single page